Using Field Parameters in DAX measure to calculate TopN
I have the below DAX Code which helps me find the top 3 values in a column based on a measure:


TopN_Values = 
VAR Top3Names =
    TOPN(3, 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES(Reports[Name]), 
            "TotalMarks", [Total_Marks]
        ), 
        [TotalMarks], DESC
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX(Top3Names, Reports[Name], ", ")    

I have now put two slicers on the page, one for Class_Name and another for Subject_Name by use of Field Parameters. How do i make this measure dynamic to reflect the topN based on the two selections? I tried using multiple combinations of switch statement but couldn't get it to work.
for example, if the Class_Name is selected as Jameson, and the Subject_Name is selected as "Science" then the code should effectively be working as:
TopN_Values = 
VAR Top3Names =
    TOPN(3, 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES(Reports[Jameson]), 
            "TotalMarks", [Science_Marks]
        ), 
        [TotalMarks], DESC
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX(Top3Names, Reports[Jameson], ", ") 


Can you share a .pbix?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eO1FhrG6hYRX_mFnxuByUkJdVLzHUW33/view?usp=sharing

I'm confused as to why you have used field parameters given your question. Try this and see if it gives you what you want.
Transform your data into this shape as follows:

let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ZZDLCoMwEEX/JWsXTmJiXPb9WLZLkVKqoNDqwvT/OzcQ2rGbQwjnTm6mrtU1vNtuDLeVytT5/urmaeSTM4xKM6xnaDKqyb7yWsg+eoRECdnkQt4I2UIpgBIgT0LeyskFw+gEKryQd3x3mUI/P/rh2eJ9lDVxbp7HKlYE9suAcUCV+pN2wj8sfQffokuJEPGHf/3j0rfYI5fgJEBW7vH0N98neMzXmvs3Hw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, Class_Name = _t, Science_Marks = _t, Math_Marks = _t, Biology_Marks = _t, #"Total Marks" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Class_Name", type text}, {"Science_Marks", Int64.Type}, {"Math_Marks", Int64.Type}, {"Biology_Marks", Int64.Type}, {"Total Marks", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Total Marks"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Name", "Class_Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","_Marks","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"Attribute", "Subject"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"

Create a measure as follows:
SUM_Total = SUM('Table'[Value])

In your slicers, add the columns directly. e.g.


Everything should now work as desired. Click a slicer and the results will update.


Thanks for the solution. This is a dummy data and there are lot of other fields which is correlated and hence i am not in a position to do the unpivot.  The current file is a dummy which i created for easy understanding but mostly i need help with DAX if possible.
Is there any easy way to just use the field parameter in DAX?

Even if this is dummy data, the principle still stands. Your data has the incorrect structure and will always needs to be unpivoted. This isn't a problem for field parameters and is a data transformation exercise.
